# How to link domain to content in subfolder not showing subfolder in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

i have a site and want to try different CMS for managing it. So i createded subfolders under document root:

> /cms/drupal/index.php
>
> /cms/joomla/index.php
>
> /cms/wordpress/index.php

To make the domain point to the subfolder i have created a htaccess file in document root
with the following content (taken from [this site](http://mosmostech.com/2012/06/htaccess-rewrite-to-remove-a-subfolder)):

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

## Load site from Drupal CMS subfolder
#
RewriteRule   ^$ cms/drupal/
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ cms/drupal/$1

## Load site from Joomla! CMS subfolder
#
RewriteRule   ^$ cms/joomla/
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ cms/joomla/$1

## Load site from WordPress CMS subfolder
#
RewriteRule   ^$ cms/wordpress/
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ cms/wordpress/$1
```

This makes loading the domain without a query string directly from the targeted subfolder and without showing 'cms/drupal' in the URL. However, as soon as i click on a link, the subfolder appears in URL like

> http://www.example.com/cms/drupal/index.php?query=string

1. Can you tell me, how to set up the htaccess file in document root to allow for loading from the subfolders like shown above and not revealing the subfolder(s) in the URL?
2. Can you tell me, how to make all the links on the site keep all query string data but not showing the subfolder(s) in the URL?